# Ubuntu can't launch any program

Tags: snap

I am new to Ubuntu. Whenever I try to launch a program via terminal I get this log:

`cannot create user data directory: /home/rodrigo/snap/firefox/2277: Bad message`

I think it has something to do with snap but I'm nkt quite sure. Anybody has any solutions?

Comment: Is your `/home` or `/home/rodrigo` a symlink to a different mounted drive? That could mean a problem for `snap` apps.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the output of the commands `ls -ld /home /home/rodrigo /home/rodrigo/snap`, `df /home/rodrigo` and `df`. Did you install the system yourself?